# Make Amazon web app and Unity lens search Amazon.co.uk instead of .com

Tags: shopping-lens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the shopping lens be changed to display results from Amazon.co.uk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204829/can-the-shopping-lens-be-changed-to-display-results-from-amazon-co-uk)

I'm from Portugal and I use Amazon.co.uk a lot. The problem is that the web app and the new Unity shopping lens only show results from Amazon.com.

Can I change the default to search `amazon.co.uk`? How?