# Can the shopping lens be changed to display results from Amazon.co.uk?

Tags: shopping-lens

How can I configure the dash's shopping lens to fetch its search results from *www.amazon.co.uk* instead of *www.amazon.com*?

Is there any program for controlling the lenses or another settings under Unity for customizing them?

Comment: Is it possible to just specify Physi-CD results from that - [e.g.](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search//www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_p_n_date_1?rh=n:163856011,n:!624868011,n:625061011,n:625065011,p_n_date:1249097011&bbn=625065011&ie=UTF8&qid=1399712115&rnid=1249095011&ajr=0) changed to Yearly CD low-cost-side/bar~pickmackup, mountable ; - /dev/sr0 ?
=======

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
```

change to read

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Amazon
Type=Application
Icon=amazon-store
#Exec=unity-webapps-runner --amazon
Exec=unity-webapps-runner -d amazon.co.uk
```

is a basic workaround for the moment.

Comment: Thanks Tim.
For me the file doesn't exist. It's /usr/share/app-install/desktop/unity-webapps-common:ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
for me, no idea why. Your change does work in that file too. (Sorry can't comment yet)

Comment: Now ,you can comment :)

Comment: Thanks for this @Felix - I have `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/unity-webapps-common:ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop` as well, however a change in this file has no effect for me - only `/usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop` has me going to the desired locale's url. I also note that visiting amazon.com via the webapp runner normally inserts a tag for the affiliate program (which helps to fund ubuntu development) - to restore this use `amazon.co.uk/?tag=u1webapp-uk-21`, which works fine.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/192725/how-do-i-make-sure-that-canonical-get-affiliate-benefits-when-i-buy-from-amazon) for more on the affiliate tag.

Comment: Just a note to say that this does not work for Saucy.  The syntax of unity-webapps-runner seems to have changed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there's no such option **via the GUI** at the moment (see *Tim Booth*'s [suggested solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/204851/86380) for a workaround using the terminal), tho the dash and its lenses is a work in progress, and a settings panel is to be integrated in the next releases.

From *Mark Shuttleworth*'s [original blog post](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1182) on the shopping lens (which is shaped in the form of a Q&A page):

> **I want to control this in the settings!**
>
> [...] designs and work are under way to make that possible. 
>   That should land in 12.10 too, or as an update, or in 13.04.

You can get a peek preview of things to come with this mock design, as [suggested](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/is-an-off-switch-for-the-shopping-lens-in-the-works) (and mocked) by *Sam Hewitt*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion from Tim Booth help me to try with the commands, based in his solution I tried with the follow Line:

```
    Exec=unity-webapps-runner -h smile.amazon.de -i NULL
```

I am connecting with the site in Germany, -h is for homepage and -i for the App ID. At the moment works fine.