# Ubuntu 13.10 Dash

Tags: 13.10, unity-dash

Is there a way to customize the shopping url for my country.

By default if I type ebay:vanity in the dash it returns results from ebay.com

I am in Australia and I want to search ebay.com.au

Comment: This function is not implemented to help you, but to spy on you. You do not want to use it. Use your browser.

Comment: mondjudge thanks for your concern, not sure whether this has changed in 13.10 see here:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/Canonical-Makes-the-Search-in-Ubuntu-13-10-Completely-Anonymous-385199.shtml

Comment: I found a question with answers to change the url in the amazon lens. It is a workaround, but maybe this also works for the ebay lens: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204829/can-the-shopping-lens-be-changed-to-display-results-from-amazon-co-uk

Comment: mondjunge, thank you again for your reply.
It seems this was a work around in 12.10 but is not available in 13.10.
Also there is no reference to ebay in the dir: /usr/share/applications

Thank you for your time.